# hard time understand jquery (sizzel) performance results

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, sizzle

While trying to improve my app performance and came up with the following question.

Which of the two will be more efficient?

```
let arr = $('#nav-questions, #nav-jobs, #nav-docs > small, #nav-tags')
```

or

```
   let arr = [
        $('#nav-questions'),
        $('#nav-jobs'),
        $('#nav-docs > small'),
        $('#nav-tags')
        ];
```

Suprisingly the test results points that the second implementation is much faster (Tested on chrome 60)

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6aog79u1/)

[image]

So now the question is, How come? And why?

FYI: I've considered that jquery indexes the results, same results on new instance of the same page.

Comment: Can you show your full testing code?

Comment: @micnic It's mentioned in the question, I did figured that it might be Sizzel indexing my results, thats why I performed the test on two different tabs of the same page

Comment: I can replicate the OP's results. https://jsperf.com/sizzel-comma/1

Comment: @JamesThorpe added the code to fiddle

Comment: I'm getting [entirely different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXzgs.png) if I paste and run that code against this page.  Also Chrome 60, on Windows.

Comment: Probably the fact that jQuery converts lone ID selectors to getElementById() calls? Then you'd essentially be comparing three getElementById() calls and one selector call to a list of four selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock it sounds right, I will check it later today with non-id selector + comparison to 'querySelectorAll'